# How to remove onremovable folder in root of device via adb

Tags: android, adb, root

I accidentally created folder in root of my device. When i try delete it,via `rm -rf` I get an error,what it read-only folder.

When i try to do `mount -o rw,remount /lib` I get an error:

```
'/lib' not in /proc/mounts
```

Whether exist remove this unremovable folder via adb? Thanks everybody for any help.

Comment: My phone is rooted.

Comment: `/lib` is not a mount point. I would expect that the mount point is `/` so try `mount -o rw,remount /`

Comment: @Robert Yes,it works ok,but why for /system i haven't this error? Thank you very much again.

Comment: @Robert o no,i deleted my folder,did mount -o ro,remount /,but when i try to do the same for system folder i ge Device or resource busy error.

Comment: Please check mount points via `mount` what partitions are mounted. Only older devices have `/system` mount points.